# XSD schema for unordered mandatory and optional tags

Tags: xsd

I want to express unordered mandatory and optional tags occurring  reccurringly in an XSD.
Can any one tell how this problem can be resolved ?
If it is not feasible, what is the approach that can be taken.

**UPDATE**

```
<xs:element name="Tag1" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Tag2" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Tag3" type="xs:string" maxoccurs="Unbounded"/>
```

All these tags appear under a complext type and tag1 and tag2 are mandatory. tag3 is optional and can occur any number of times. tag1, tag2 and tag3 can appear in any order

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking questions here, it is usual to post some code to demonstrate the challenge you are facing. Often, by writing code to demonstrate a problem you end up solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "all" group selector and use minOccurs to indicate mandatory-ness.

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Message1" targetNamespace="http://Message1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="TheValue" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="TheValue2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This are correct:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Message1">
  <TheValue2>somevalue</TheValue2>
  <TheValue>somevalue</TheValue>
</ns0:Root>
```

and so it this:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Message1">
  <!--<TheValue2>somevalue</TheValue2>-->
  <TheValue>somevalue</TheValue>
</ns0:Root>
```

But not this:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Message1">
  <!--<TheValue2>somevalue</TheValue2>-->
  <!--<TheValue>somevalue</TheValue>-->
</ns0:Root>
```

Comment: the mandatory tags and recurring optional tags are all listed under a single complex type tag..your solution does not fit in my question

Comment: Your question does not supply sufficient detail. My answer is to the following: "unordered mandatory and optional tags". If you are not satisfied with the answer then please clarify your question rather than the answer offered, or you risk appearing ungrateful.

Comment: <xs:element name="Tag1" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Tag2" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Tag3" type="xs:string" maxoccurs="Unbounded"/>
All these tags appear under a complext type and tag1 and tag2 are mandatory. tag3 is optional and can occur any number of times. tag1, tag2 and tag3 can 
appear  in any order

Comment: I have added your comment as an edit to your original question. however, I still don't understand what you are asking. Are you providing the answer to your question?